# How to set function to class in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a function

```
function log() {
    console.log('something');
}
```

that I want this object to have:

```
class Car {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  log() {
    // something
  }
}
```

How can I attach it without repeating the code inside the function?

Comment: `Car.log = log;`

Comment: @WaisKamal that will add a static function. Not the same as the second one

Comment: You can do: `Object.assign(Car.prototype, { log })`

Answer (score 1):

Like this

Either as a member function OR on the prototype

```js
class Car {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  log = str => console.log(str); // or log = log if log is defined elsewhere
}

const carA = new Car();
carA.log("vroom");

// or

const logger = str => console.log(str);

Car.prototype.logger = logger;

const carB = new Car();
carA.logger("vroom"); // also available to the previous and other Car objects
carB.logger("vroom");
```

Comment: That is repeating the code inside the function.

Comment: How so. I define only one function in that script so no repetition

Comment: I want to use a function that was defined separately.

Comment: is it also possible with Object.setPrototypeOf()?

Comment: I do not know or have used that method. I think not, when I look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the function as a method on the `Car` prototype, so now it will be available as a method on all instances.

```js
function log() {
    console.log('something');
}

class Car {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

Car.prototype.log = log;

const a = new Car("Audi");
const b = new Car("BMW");

a.log();
b.log();
```

Comment: beat you to it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can do it in three ways;

first way is by using class constructor and passing function in constructor call

```js
function log() {
    console.log('something');
}


class Car {
  constructor(name,log) {
    this.name = name;
    this.log = log
  }
  
}
const audi = new Car("name",log);
audi.log();
```

second way is by simply using equal operator

```js
function log() {
    console.log('something');
}


class Car {
  constructor(name,log)  {
    this.name = name;
  }
  log = log
  
}


const audi =  new Car("some");
audi.log();
```

Third way is by using prototype

```js
function log() {
    console.log('something');
}


class Car {
  constructor(name,log) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
}

Car.prototype.log = log;

const audi =  new Car("some");
audi.log();
```

Comment: How can I add a getter method using the prototype method?

Comment: Actually there is no direct way but can be done via following way -class foo {
  constructor(){
    this.a = "something";
  }
}
class bar extends foo {
  constructor(){
    super();

  }
  method() {
   return this.a
  }
}
const newBar = new bar ();
console.log(newBar.method())